# How do I reach a git repo on my home network?

Tags: linux, git, networking

I have a raspberry pi that I want to use to host my git repos.  I have created a host on no-ip.org that just redirects to my router and I setup port forwarding on my router to redirect a certain port to my pi.  I can ssh into my pi using this host name and port (I think I had to change the ssh daemon on my pi to not use the standard port 22).

So now I want to know what url would I use for my git remote to access a git repo on my pi if it is located at ~/repos/myrepo.git.  I have tried **http://my-url/~/repos/myrepo.git** but that doesn't work.  I've also just tried the pi's IP address and the absolute path to the repo, such as **//192.168.1.3/home/david/repos/myrepo.git** but that also does not work.

I'd like to be able to access my repos using the no-ip host I created so that I can access them from anywhere, but I'll settle for using the local IP if I have to.  Oh, I'm trying to access my pi from a Windows box if that matters.

Comment: did you read https://git-scm.com/book/ca/v1/Git-on-the-Server (the whole chapter 4, not just this page)?

Comment: I did not.  I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to njzk2 for telling me to RTFM I was able to figured it out.  I went with the SSH protocol and had to use the format **david@my-url:~/repos/myrepo.git** and that worked.